# How to find direction name between two zipcodes in C# using google API

Tags: c#, google-api

I want to find the direction name(N,S,NE,NW,SE,SW,E,W) between two zip codes.

Example from 99501 to 35004 let say the direction is North then i need to get North as the result.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried anything?  what issues have you run into?  You have to provide a bit more details of the issue, people aren't going to do everything for you...

Comment: I'm much new to it,just need suggestions or approach how it can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

A little Googling and you can find a list of zip codes with their corresponding lat/lng coordinates.
https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666
Now you only need a way to calculate bearing (https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and use that value to figure out direction name.

For short distances (county or even state level) this will work, but once you accuracy will drop off at some point.